# How to extend background colour to full width on left and right with 2 column layout

Tags: css, overflow, background-color

I am trying to achieve an effect with a two column layout, where the left hand column extends its background colours out to the left, to full width, and the right column extends its background colours out to the right, to full width.

So it's like "full width bands" but a different colour to the left as to the right... so in [this example screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7qw0ts1lqgxhp7/Screenshot%202014-03-05%2022.40.34.png) we would have a full width yellow band then a full width mint band on the left, but a full width green band then a full width maroon band on the right.

Is this possible with CSS, and if so, how?

I googled and found some examples using

```
overflow-x:hidden
```

But these seem to only apply to a "full width band" with the same colour both left and right. Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<div id="div1">
    <div>Left div</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div>Right div</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#div1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}

#div1 div {
    padding-left:30%;
}

#div2 div {
    padding-right: 30%;
}

#div2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    background: green;
}
```

2 container divs that are 50% width and floated left/right. Then a div inside each of them with padding left/right.

Might work, depending on your existing code structure!  See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dCEKA/.